# What header string can I use for PEF identification for file recovery?

Tags: raw, pentax, file-recovery

I use Linux for handling my pictures. I lost a disk that contains a lot of Pentax PEF files and JPEG files. I was able to recover the JPEG files with the tool `foremost`. It can be configured to recover the PEF files too but for that I need the *header* for the PEF files (One header for JPEG it seems to be `\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10`).

Has anybody an idea what I should add for PEF? Is `\x4d\x4d\x00\x2a` enough?
Is there another tool that I could use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) is a similar sort of program which can handle the recovery of PEF files according to their list of supported [file formats](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec)

Comment: At this moment I am getting my files back. It was already installed together with `testdisk` but I was unaware of it.

Answer (score 3):

I checked with PEF files from my K20D, K-5 and K-3. The former two's files begin with `4D 4D 00 2A` ("MM.*"), but the K-3's begin with `49 49 2A 00` ("II*.").

Maybe older or newer models use even different codes. I suggest you look or ask for specific PEF files matching your own models first, then use those 4 bytes for header detection. Since they're all using a 00 byte, and only occur at the start of a file when looked up by file recovery software, this should be a safe procedure, avoiding random occurances of those patterns. At worst, you'll get some *false positives*, which you can then later sort out. For instance, running the `exiftool` program over each file afterwards may help identify valid PEF files, and sort out by bad ones.

Comment: You've discovered the [TIFF header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#Byte_order), which has two variations to allow different byte orders. PEF files are based on TIFF, as are most other raw formats.